# How can i create a locator for the below element for Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to create an Xpath to click on radioButton. see below element and xpath from the web:

Xpath:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/label[1]/input
```

ELEMENT:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="dataRow[column.map]" name="optionsRadios" value="15" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

Comment: Please share your HTML page. You can do `driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/label[1]/input"))`, but maybe there's a better solution. And it is impossible to know if we don't see the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you see a name on a tag, that's probably a good bet to start with short of an ID.

```
//input[@name='optionsRadios']
```

I would suggest that you use a CSS selector instead because they are faster, better supported, and the syntax is simpler, easier to understand.

```
input[name='optionsRadios']
```

[W3C Selectors Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview)

Answer (score 0):

Prefer to use CSS selectors rather then xpath.

css=input.ng-pristine ng-valid
or 
css=input[name=optionsRadios]

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to interact (possibly `click()`) is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following (Java) solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.ng-pristine.ng-valid[name='optionsRadios'][ng-model*='column']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid' and @name='optionsRadios'][contains(@ng-model,'column')]"))).click();
  ```